# Disney dole whip variants

Tags: ingredient-selection, drinks, pineapple

Does Disney’s dole whip come in flavors besides pineapple?
Disney must have had some ideas along those lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [manufacturer’s website](https://blog.dolesoftserve.com/2016/03/31/dole-whip-vs-dole-soft-serve/):

> The pineapple flavor is most popular at Disney Parks, but a total of 6 bold, refreshing fruit flavors are available for purchase **Pineapple, Orange, Strawberry, Raspberry, Mango and Lemon**.